# Как обновить один item после изменения в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

`RecyclerView` отображает список `CardView` с текстом, их можно добавлять и удалять.
Проблема вот в чем, я пытаюсь реализовать изменение itema, то есть, на `card view` по мимо текста есть еще и кнопка change, которая вызывает `FragmentDialog` в котором есть `editText` для ввода строчки замены. Я вставляю измененный объект Item в мой DataList и потом в `onBindViewHolder` в `onClick` я вызываю `notifyItemChanged(position);` и item на экране не обновляется, а в DataList все нормально, новый объект на той же позиции. Как тогда обновить item на экране? 
После перезапуска приложения, естественно item обновленный.

UPD:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
List<ListItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    loadData();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(list, this, getFragmentManager());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void loadData() {
    list.add(new ListItem("Item1"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item2"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item3"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item4"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item5"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item6"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Item7"));

}
```

}

В адаптере

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new MyDialog(list, position).show(fragmentManager, "myDialog");
            notifyItemChanged(position);


        }
    });


}
```

В DialogFragment

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public MyDialog(List<ListItem> list, int position) {
    this.list = list;
    this.position = position;

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
    name = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    buttonOk = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    buttonCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);


    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonOk) {

        String nameText = name.getText().toString();
        ListItem item = list.get(position);
        item.setTitle(nameText);
        list.set(position, item);
        dismiss();

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonCancel) {

        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: можно увидеть как и где вы устанавливаете адаптер в ресайкл?

Comment: Немного не понял, именно где я setAdapter(adapter);  вызываю? Если так, то в MainActivity. Или код самого адаптера скинуть?

Comment: мне интересно где именно в MainActivity

Comment: Обновил, скинул код activity.

Comment: Пробовал еще ставить адаптер в onResume(); 
Item обновляется, но после перехода на другое activity, а после DialogFragment все также ничего.

Comment: а как вы из `FragmentDialog` добавляете `Item` в  `DataList`? `DataList` это переданный в адаптер `list`?

Comment: Дополнил код.
Да, он самый, а в адаптере передаю на диалог.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что `list` вы передали в диалогфрагмент, там изменили один `item` в нем, а дальше диалогфрагмент закрывается, открывается прежняя активити и лист в `onCreate` формируется заново, поэтому изменений нет. Странно что после перезапуска приложения (по вашим словам) в этом `list` происходят обновления. Нужно же как то дать знать `list` в `activity`, что один из его `item` обновился, и не создавать в этой позиции `new ListItem("Item...")`, а вставить изменный item и далее в адаптер

Comment: или обновленный вы имеете ввиду - прежний - как и был?

Comment: После диалога onCreate по моему не вызывается, activity видно на заднем плане, после закрытия оно по идее должно восстановиться.
 Может это я что то путаю.
Дело в том что в случае с добавлением, это работает, только я передавал adapter в другой dialogFragment и уже в этом диалоге, после вставки елемента в list, я вызывал notifyItemInserted(); И все работало.

Comment: Активити на заднем фоне это смена состояния его [жизненного цикла](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). Возвращение в фокус это срабатывание onCreate. Сохранение всего что нужно сохранить необходимо продумывать и на это есть несколько вариантов. В данном случае мы ничего не сохраняем. Мы гоняем list туда-сюда

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем мысли следующие. Нужно передать обновленный `list` из `MyDialog` в `MainActivity`

1. в `MyDialog`объявим переменную и создадим интерфейс

   ```
   Communicator communicator;

   //.... 

   public interface Communicator {
        public void messageList(List<ListItem> list); 
           }
   ```
2. В `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` допишем `implements
       MyDialog.Communicator`
3. Вынесем вызов адаптера в отдельный метод

   ```
   private void updateRecyclerView(List<ListItem> list){
       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
       adapter = new MyAdapter(list, this, getFragmentManager());
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
4. В `public class MainActivity` реализуем метод интерфейса `MyDialog.Communicator`

   ```
   @Override
   public void messageList(List<ListItem> listFromDialog) {
        this.list = listFromDialog;
        updateRecyclerView(list);

   }
   ```
5. в `MyDialog` в `onClick` вызовем `communicator.messageList(list)`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonOk) {

      String nameText = name.getText().toString();
      ListItem item = list.get(position);
      item.setTitle(nameText);
      list.set(position, item);
      dismiss();
      communicator.messageList(list);//<--------------


   } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonCancel) {

      dismiss();
   }
   ```
6. В `MainActivity` в `onCreate` проверяем

   ```
   if (list != null) {
       updateRecyclerView(list);
   } else {
       updateRecyclerView(loadData());
   }
   ```

*Наверняка сходу что-то не учел, будем додумывать если что*

update

> В точности повторил, кидает NullPointer в этой строке
>   communicator.messageList(list); java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
>   com.example.user.myapplication.MyDialog$Communicator.message‌​List(java.util.List)‌​'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.example.user.myapplication.MyDialog.onClick(MyDialog.jav‌​a:66)

7. Возможно контекста не хватает. Можно попробовать добавить в `MyDialog`

   ```
    @Override
      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

       super.onAttach(activity);

          if (activity instanceof Communicator) {
           communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
         } else {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + ” must implemenet MyDialog.communicator”);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Я попробую решить проблему вашим способом вечером, и напишу о результате! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В точности повторил, кидает NullPointer в этой строке `communicator.messageList(list);`

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.user.myapplication.MyDialog$Communicator.messageList(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.user.myapplication.MyDialog.onClick(MyDialog.java:66)`

Comment: Спасибо, я решил проблему! Повесил слушатель прямо во ViewHoldere, и вызываю notifyItemChange в диалоге. Все работает, но скорее всего это костыль, я так думаю.

Comment: @Максим: мой ответ не помог получается?

Comment: NullPoiter выкидывает.
Я не могу понять по чему.

Comment: Но вам огромное спасибо, за то что откликнулись и за потраченное время!

Comment: Все таки я сделал по нормальному, только callback немного по другому пробросил и все заработало.

Comment: @Максим. Опишите что как по возможности мне будет интересно

Comment: Все так же как вы и писали, только немного измененный код.
В классе MyDialog интерфейс с методом `void messageList(int position);` и еще один метод `registerCommunicator(Communicator communicator)` инициализируем comunicator. Дальше в `onClick` вызываю `comunicator.messageList(position);` В `Activity` реализую интерфейс, метод `@Override
    public void messageList(int position) {
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    };` и в `onCreate` в адаптер передаю activity. В адаптере в ViewHolder вешаю `onClick` на button, передаю позицию в диалог и вызываю `register(activity)`.